# How to copy the boot file from a bootable ISO to another non-bootable ISO?

Tags: boot, iso-image, window, bootable-media

I have two Windows 98SE ISO files, the first one is a "Bootable ISO", but the second one is "non-bootable" ISO.

I want to copy the boot file from the first iso that is already a "bootable ISO", to the second iso that is "non-bootable ISO".

So, how to extract the boot file from the "bootable ISO"?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear on what you're asking for. Please provide more info. in order to make it answerable.

Comment: Making a ISO bookable is more then just copying files.  You must alter the boot sector, and setup a boot-loader.  What OS is on these disks?  What tools do you have?

Comment: @Zoredache: The OS is `windows 98SE`, and I have `UltraISO` program.

Answer (score 1):

[<s>Windmills</s> Bootable ISOs Do Not Work That Way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQg8JKo_3ZQ).
It is not simply a matter of copying some files over - A bootable ISO image must conform to the [El Torito specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard)) (non-bootable images will typically *not* conform to this specification, and have no boot information on them).

[There are some instructions floating around the net, including these using Ultra-ISO](http://htluo.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-make-non-bootable-iso-image.html) which explain how to copy the boot data from a bootable ISO onto a non-bootable one.  This basically involves rewriting the ISO file (and in the case of the instructions I've linked to you would need a bootable ISO of the same OS in order to extract the boot blocks).
Similar results could be achieved with other tools.

Comment: Is that means, I can't do that?